# How to replace the key name in Serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelSerializer:

```
class PublicNetwokSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    PublicNetwok
    """
    class Meta:
        model = PublicNetwok
        fields = "__all__"
```

The model is bellow:

```
class PublicNetwok(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    ...
```

You know if I use the ModelSerializer I will get all the key-values like bellow:

```
[
 {
  "name":"xxx",
  "desc":"xxx",
 },
 {
  "name":"xxx",
  "desc":"xxx",
 }
]
```

But I want to change the key `desc` to `description`, in Django-Rest-Framework how to access that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PublicNetwokSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    description = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_alternate_name')

    class Meta:
        model = PublicNetwok
        fields = ('name', 'description')

    def get_alternate_name(self, obj):
        return obj.desc
```